# SQL : Sum by criteria

Tags: sql, oracle, sum, criteria

I'm working with Oracle and cannot achieve the query I need for the moment.

Suppose I have the following table :

```
- ID    Date    Type    Value
 - 1    01/12/2016  prod    1
 - 2    01/01/2017  test    10
 - 3    01/06/2017  test    20
 - 4    01/12/2017  prod    30
 - 5    15/12/2017  test    40
 - 6    01/01/2018  test    50
 - 7    01/06/2018  test    60
 - 8    01/12/2018  prod    70
```

I need to sum the VALUES between the "prod" TYPES + the last "prod" VALUE.
The results should be :

```
- 1 01/01/2016 - 1
- 2 01/01/2017 - 60
- 3 01/06/2017 - 60
- 4 01/12/2017 - 60
- 5 15/12/2017 - 220
- 6 01/01/2018 - 220
- 7 01/06/2018 - 220
- 8 01/12/2018 - 220
```

I first had to sum VALUES by YEAR without taking TYPES into account.
The need changed and I don't see how to start to identify, for each line, which is the previous "prod" DATE and sum each VALUE including the last "prod" TYPE.

Thanks

Comment: What if there's one or more rows which have a non-prod type after the last prod row? e.g. `9 02/12/2018 test 80` and `10 03/12/2018 test 90`. Should those rows have sum values of 170, or should it be null?

Comment: Good question :). Those rows should be summed.

Comment: @Boneist : your question about the way non-"prod" values should be handled was good ! I've been struggling with inconsistent data and have just found that I find this case in the data. So the question now is, how to have data from the current year grouped even if no "prod" value exists then group by prod values ?

Comment: I suggest you raise this as a new question, with sample input data that shows the scenario you need help with, along with the output you want to get.

Answer (score 5):

You can define the groups using a cumulative sum on `type = 'PROD'` -- in reverse, then use a window function for the final summation:

```
select t.*,
       sum(value) over (partition by grp) as total
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when type = 'PROD' then 1 else 0 end) over (order by id desc) as grp
      from t
     ) t
 order by id;
```

To see the grouping logic, look at:

```
ID    Date    Type    Value      Grp
1    01/12/2016  prod    1        3
2    01/01/2017  test    10       2
3    01/06/2017  test    20       2
4    01/12/2017  prod    30       2
5    15/12/2017  test    40       1
6    01/01/2018  test    50       1
7    01/06/2018  test    60       1
8    01/12/2018  prod    70       1
```

This identifies the groups that need to be summed.  The `DESC` is because "prod" *ends* a group.  If "prod" started a group (i.e. was included with the sum on the next row), then `ASC` would be used.

[***Rextester Demo***](https://rextester.com/IMUCT79660)

Comment: Are you sure about `desc` for `order by id desc`..?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan . . . Yes.  See the edit to the answer.

Comment: Thanks ! I'm trying to adapt this to my context and this seems pretty good. Just on more thing : how can I get the year of the "PROD" item as the content of the "grp" item ?

Comment: very nice solution congrats., I've added an order by clause with a `demo`.

Comment: @user343081 . . . I'm not sure what your comment means.  There is no "grp" item in this question -- it is added in this answer -- and there is no relationship between "year" and the groupings, based on the question.  Perhaps you should ask another question with sample data and desired results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff : "grp" is the name you gave to the grouped sum :  "sum(case when type = 'PROD' then extract(YEAR from DATE) else 0 end) over (order by id desc) as grp" did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Gordon Linoff's answer is great.
This below is just for a bit of a different flavor(12c+)

Setup:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT  = 'DD/MM/YYYY';
CREATE TABLE TEST_TABLE(
  THE_ID INTEGER,
  THE_DATE DATE,
  THE_TYPE CHAR(4),
  THE_VALUE INTEGER);

INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE VALUES (1,TO_DATE('01/12/2016'),'prod',1);
INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE VALUES (2,TO_DATE('01/01/2017'),'test',10);
INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE VALUES (3,TO_DATE('01/06/2017'),'test',20);
INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE VALUES (4,TO_DATE('01/12/2017'),'prod',30);
INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE VALUES (5,TO_DATE('15/12/2017'),'test',40);
INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE VALUES (6,TO_DATE('01/01/2018'),'test',50);
INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE VALUES (7,TO_DATE('01/06/2018'),'test',70);
INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE VALUES (8,TO_DATE('01/12/2018'),'prod',60);
COMMIT;
```

Query:

```
SELECT
THE_ID, THE_DATE, MAX(RUNNING_GROUP_SUM) OVER (PARTITION BY THE_MATCH_NUMBER) AS GROUP_SUM
FROM TEST_TABLE
MATCH_RECOGNIZE (
  ORDER BY THE_ID
  MEASURES
    MATCH_NUMBER() AS THE_MATCH_NUMBER,
    RUNNING SUM(THE_VALUE) AS RUNNING_GROUP_SUM
  ALL ROWS PER MATCH
  AFTER MATCH SKIP PAST LAST ROW
  PATTERN (TEST_TARGET{0,} PROD_TARGET)
  DEFINE TEST_TARGET AS THE_TYPE = 'test',
    PROD_TARGET AS THE_TYPE = 'prod')
ORDER BY THE_ID ASC;
```

Result:

```
    THE_ID THE_DATE    GROUP_SUM
---------- ---------- ----------
     1 01/12/2016          1
     2 01/01/2017         60
     3 01/06/2017         60
     4 01/12/2017         60
     5 15/12/2017        220
     6 01/01/2018        220
     7 01/06/2018        220
     8 01/12/2018        220
```